# What is the meaning of this message?

Tags: neoverse

A friend got this message after finishing a run in Neoverse:
[image]

What does that mean? The item is in the store, but what does that mean? What does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Steampowered, v0.995 changelog](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/994220/view/4066122160041069077):

> The Final Boss appears when you complete all the chapters in the [Transcended Universe] of 1 or above with "Unknown Stone"

> You can now enter the Semi Final boss stage only when equipped with “Unknown Stone”.